# Make a percentage table with stargazer

Tags: r, latex, percentage, stargazer

I have data that looks like this, `df1`:

```
Product Relative_Value
Car     0.12651458
Plane   0.08888552
Tank    0.03546231
Bike    0.06711630
Train   0.06382191
```

`Relative_Value` is the percentage of the total sell of the product. I use `stargazer(df1, summary=FALSE, rownames=TRUE)` to get latex code to make a nice table of the data. But how do I get either R or TeXstudio to understand that `Relative_Value` should be formatted as percentage and not decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use percent() from the `scales` package

```
library(scales)

df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Relative_Value = percent(Relative_Value))
```

Note that percent() changes the column type to character

Comment: When I run this on my df I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to mathematical function.`

Comment: Is Relative_Value a non-numeric column, perhaps by accident? Add as.numeric() to be sure, like this: `mutate(Relative_Value = percent(as.numeric(Relative_Value)))`

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it by changing Relative_Value to character (from numeric) before putting it through percent() and I got the same error as you did. That's your issue.

Comment: That was the problem it seems! Thanks :) (in the real code I added a row at the bottom to sum the Relative_Value for each df I have)